# Google Analytics - How to combine language codes - abc.com/xyz/ and abc.com/en/xyz/

Tags: google-analytics, language

I couldn't find a specific thread about combining URLs with language codes in GA but am happy to be pointed towards an existing thread.

I would like to combine abc.com/ and abc.com/en/ URLs in GA as they display the same content. Is there a way to do this within the GA GUI (filters?) without modifying analytics.js as in the article below?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: Rather than have URLs that display the same content, could you just redirect one of those URLs to the other?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Stephen's comment, having two urls with the same info is not the best user experience and is likely to be harmful to SEO.

But yes, there are a few ways to merge ga reports. First would be changing the data with a search and replace filter. Here is more on it: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Another way of doing it would be making custom reports and regex-based filters there to join pages, but it won't be able to flexibly group by joined versions of pages. That is viable only if you need to report without grouping by.

Finally, you can also override the dl dimension (document location) and the dp dimension (document path) with GTM to merge the data. You'll probably also need to override the dr (document referrer). This option would allow you to do some magic... you would be able to join all the languages urls into one url and then push the language information into a custom dimension. This will make analysis much easier any way you may need it.

But again, it's not quite adequate to patch data issues that stem from usability issues. Fixes like these should be seen as very temporary patches to be removed once front-end catches up.